# How to join a list on a list that uses groupby using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to join two list and return an object using a lambda expression.

The current query I'm trying to convert looks like:

```
var results = from w in unitsList
              group w by new{ w.UnitNo, w.Proj, w.Cred, w.Yr } into wGroup
              join m in minList 
                on new { wGroup.Key.UnitNo, wGroup.Key.Proj } 
                equals new { m.UnitNo, m.Proj } into nGroup
              select new DailyUnit(){ 
                          UnitNo = wGroup.key.UnitNo, 
                          Project = wGroup.key.Proj, 
                          Creds = wGroup.Key.Cred,
                          Years = wGroup.Key.Yr,
                          Sites = nGroup.Sum(x => x.Value) }).ToList()};
```

How do I do the group by and join using a lambda expression?

I've tried:

```
var results = unitsList.ToList().GroupBy(w => new{ w.UnitNo, w.Proj, w.Cred, w.Yr })
                                .Join(minList, w => { w.Key.UnitNo, w.Key.Proj }, 
                                    u => { u.Key.UnitNo, u.Key.Proj }, 
                                    (w,u) => new DailyUnit()
                                              { UnitNo = w.key.UnitNo, 
                                                Project = w.key.Proj, 
                                                Creds = w.Key.Cred,
                                                Years = w.Key.Yr,
                                                Sites = u.Sum(x => x.Value) 
                                               }
                                         ).ToList()};
```

Comment: Why you dont stay with your query syntax here?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm trying to figure out how to do it with lambda